# Can't make a SQL Query

Tags: sql, subquery

My task is: 
To select descriptions of products, which prices were changed at least twice in 1988 
My code:

```
    select description from PRODUCT 
    join price on product.product_id = price.product_id 
    where price.product_id = (select product_id from price having 
    count(product_id)>1)
```

Structure of DB

[image: Structure of DB]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I think you need a IN clause in where clause. Use `where price.product_id IN (subquery)`

Comment: What do you mean `price` in here?

Comment: Add a GROUP BY to the subquery! And do IN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say your are joining two tables using advantureWork2012 database where the 
ProductID is your joining key

[image]

Since Your are using Subquery with = you will get this Error

> (Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.)

[image]

you need to use IN operator instead.

[image]

and also since your are using having you need to Group by otherwise you will get an error

[image]

So back to your query you need to change it to :

```
    Select product.description From PRODUCT 
    Join price On product.product_id = price.product_id 
    where price.product_id In (select product_id from price group by 
    product_id having count(product_id)>1 and Year(Start_Date)>1988)
```

Comment: how does this account for "which prices were changed at least twice in 1988"?

Comment: @Vladislav Sorry what do mean i did get the question

Comment: I mean that your suggested query does not consider the requirements to retrieve only the products, which prices were changed at least twice in 1988. The query returns all products that are present at least twice in the "price" table.

Answer (score 1):

What DBMS are you using?

I think you can remove the join to `price` 'cause you won't need it on that, change the `=` operator in the where clause to `in` and add a condition for the year, like so:

```
select description
from PRODUCT
where product_id in (
  select product_id
  from price
  where to_char(start_date,'YYYY')='1988'
  group by product_id
  having count(product_id)>1
)
```

Assuming that you are using Oracle, I think this would work. Just change the parts specific to your DBMS, especially the condition for the year.